# Не получается собрать ссылки на категории и товары

Tags: python, парсер, bs4, xmlparser

Есть сайт

```
https://www.gzhel.ru/catalog/
```

Ввожу код

```
all_a = soup.find("div", class_="grid-4 grid-tablet-3 grid-phablet-3 grid-phone-2 js-nospace").find_all("a")
for item in all_a:
  item_url = item.get("href")
  print(item_url)
```

Не работает. Сегодня не работает....Вчера отлично работал!
Что могло произойти?

Comment: Скорее всего вас заблокировали, видимо чересчур настойчиво запросами закидали сервер)) смотрите статус код

Comment: В коде еще масса запросов которые работают........Если бы заблочили, то полностью....или я не прав?

Comment: Пока писал коммент.......попробовал еще раз...сделал копипаст на новую строку и он сработал.....)))))) или это тупит Colab?